# Unexpected Element found exception while marshalling the XML response

Tags: java, xml, web-services, soap, jaxb

I am consuming a SOAP webservice in my application and i am using JAXB for marshalling/unmarshalling the XML request/response. I was using apache-cxf client for client code generation.

The  Service provider added an extra field in the response. However, I am not making use of that field. But still addition of a new simple string type field to the already existing complex type disturbed the service and I am getting the below error.

"javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: Unmarshalling Error: unexpected element (uri:"http://", local:"aaa")"

Could some one please help me in fixing this issue without regenrating the client code?

Answer (score 0):

You have to regenerate client code, because contract was changed by provider.
It is very bad idea to put any workaround for that.